# Primes of the form $p=a^2-2b^2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratic-reciprocity

I've stumbled upon this and I was wondering if anyone here could come up with a simple proof:

Let $p$ be a prime such that $p\equiv 1 \bmod 8$, and let $a,b\geq 1$ such that 
$$p=a^2-2b^2.$$
**Question**: Is $b$ necessarily a square modulo $p$?

I have plenty of numerical data to support an affirmative answer, but the proof eludes me so far. For instance:
\begin{align*}
17 & = 5^2 - 2\cdot 2^2\\
&= 7^2 - 2\cdot 4^2\\
& = 23^2 - 2\cdot 16^2\\
& = 37^2 - 2\cdot 26^2\\
& = 133^2 - 2\cdot 94^2\\
\end{align*}
and $2\equiv 36$, $4$, $16$, $26\equiv 9$, $94\equiv 9 \bmod 17$ are squares.

Thanks!

Comment: Try factoring: $(a+\sqrt{2}b)(a-\sqrt{2} b)\equiv 0 \mod p$ $\implies$ $a \equiv \sqrt{2} b \mod p$.  If $a$ is an integer $\mod p$, then $\sqrt{2} b$ is an integer $\mod p$.  Thus, can we conclude that $b$ is a square $\mod p$?

Comment: I don't think one can simply work modulo $p$. Notice that $1^2-2\cdot 3^2\equiv 0 \bmod 17$, but $3$ is not a square mod $17$.

Comment: Can someone explain to me the fault my logic?  $a=1$, $b=3$ doesn't satisfy $p \equiv 1 \mod 8$ as a counterexample, but I still feel unsure about my idea.

Comment: @Matt Do you want to work with negative primes, too? $$a^2-2b^2=1^2-2\cdot 3^2=-17$$

Comment: @Matt Your logic is unclear. What is "an integer mod $p$"? And why is being "an integer mod $p$" imply being a square mod $p$? Also, when you say $a\equiv \sqrt{2}b\pmod p$, what exactly do you mean? (I am not saying that there is no meaning, but from your comment, it's not clear that you understand how to make sense of it.)

Comment: @DonAntonio Is it wrong to consider $-17 \equiv 7 \mod 8$?

Comment: @AlexB. I meant that initially we pick $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ but maybe that is an unfair assumption.  Using the roots we have $a- \sqrt{2} b \equiv 0 \mod p$ implying $a\equiv \sqrt{2}b \mod p$

Comment: @matt Not at all. I though think that in most problems of this kind it is tacitly assumed everybody is a positive integer, but that might be only a bias of mine.

Comment: @DonAntonio My point was to throw out the counterexample given because that gives us a negative prime to start with.  But it turns out that the equivalence still holds

Comment: For those who would be interested, here is a related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/197918/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since $p\equiv 1\pmod 8$, $2$ is a square modulo $p$. It will therefore be enough to show that any odd prime divisor of $b$ is also a square modulo $p$. Then any prime divisor of $b$ will be a square modulo $p$, therefore $b$ itself will be.

Let $q$ be an odd prime divisor of $b$, and consider your equation modulo $q$. You find that $p\equiv a^2 \pmod{q}$, so that $p$ is a square modulo $q$. By quadratic reciprocity (using that $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$), $q$ is a square modulo $p$.

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure how I missed this. I think it is an indication that I need a nap today. Thanks again!

Comment: You need Alvaro's original condition $p \equiv 1 \bmod 8$, not just $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$, to handle the case $q = 2$.

Comment: @KCd: thanks Keith, fixed it.